# Change SIZE and ALPHA of the dots in ggboxplot? (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to change the SIZE and ALPHA parameters of the dots in my ggboxplot, any idea how to do this?

```
ggboxplot(g, x = "cluster", y = "entropy", width = 0.8,
          fill = "cluster", palette = c("#FF2079","royalblue","yellow","#FFDB00FF", 
                                        "orange","#00FECA", "olivedrab2","#fb9a99", 
                                        "#08F7FE","#00B3FF","firebrick1", "#00B3FF","orangered", 
                                        "firebrick1","firebrick1", "#fb9a99","#DBFF00FF","#FFDB00FF",
                                        "#49FF00FF"),
          order = c("1", "2", "3","5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"),
          ylab = "entropy", xlab = "clusters",  add = "jitter",
          ggtheme = theme_bw(base_size = 5), size=0.1)+ theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but while I was looking for an answer, I found the solution:

```
add.params = list(size = 3, alpha = 0.5).
```

So your code should be like this:

```
ggboxplot(g, x = "cluster", y = "entropy", width = 0.8,
add.params = list(size = 3, alpha = 0.5),
      fill = "cluster", palette = c("#FF2079","royalblue","yellow","#FFDB00FF", 
                                    "orange","#00FECA", "olivedrab2","#fb9a99", 
                                    "#08F7FE","#00B3FF","firebrick1", "#00B3FF","orangered", 
                                    "firebrick1","firebrick1", "#fb9a99","#DBFF00FF","#FFDB00FF",
                                    "#49FF00FF"),
      order = c("1", "2", "3","5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"),
      ylab = "entropy", xlab = "clusters",  add = "jitter",
      ggtheme = theme_bw(base_size = 5), size=0.1)+ theme_classic()
```